# Jquery smartlists default tag

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway to set any other tag as default tag for the smartlists instead of the default view all tags?

eg. I haf "fruits, vegetables, meat" tags. I want to set fruits as my default tag, instead of "All"

cheers~~~

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [this](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/smartlists/jquery/jquery_example.html), try

```
defaultDropdownOptText: "fruits"
```

Comment: thx for the reply. but that only changes the default "All items". I need the list to be filtered by "fruits" by default (once the list is loaded). my apologize if i didn make my question clear earlier.